# Remotely running batches on a Windows PC

Tags: windows-7, batch, remote, remote-access, remote-control

I want to remotely control my home desktop PC (running Windows 7 Professional), mainly to perform the following tasks:

1. Downloading email attachments, and sending emails with attachments
2. Running UI-less programs whose only inputs are files and whose only outputs are files

So far, the only solution I have found is to use Remote Desktop to connect to my PC, but this is very slow and inefficient, especially when there is no fast Internet connection available other than my cell phone's.

I would like to be able to send batch commands to my PC, like:

1. Download an email attachment
2. Use it as input for an UI-less program
3. Save the program's output to a file
4. Send that file to myself as an email attachment

Is this possible? How could I do it?

Comment: Is there any possibility you would consider switching to linux - or at least running a linux virtual machine on your desktop?

Comment: @Paul: Nope. Most of the UI-less programs I run are actually wrappers that use Automation to call Excel and run add-ins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to turn on the Windows Features "[X] Telnet Server" and use a telnet client to access it. This provides text based access to the windows command line so it's very light on network bandwidth.

Comment: Ugh! I thought I would add to this old question since the answer as given is EXTREMELY dangerous!  You should **NEVER** expose TELNET to the Internet as it has no effective security at all.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: DO NOT USE TELNET OVER THE INTERNET**

You need a secure method if wanting to expose a command line over the Internet. Arguably the most secure is Secure Shell (SSH). This is available for Windows via [Bitvise WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) which has a limited free license for non-commercial use.

There are other options for Windows SSH servers too. See this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows for details.